# Can't communicate from content script to popup in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying my hand at my first Chrome Extension.
I've stumbled upon an issue where I can't communicate from the content script to the popup.

**Context:**
My popup contains some localStorage data that I want to retrieve from the content script at the refresh/init of a page so I can use that data on the page.

If I understand the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) correctly this should be possible.
It says:

"Sending a request from a content script looks like this:"

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

So I've tried that and I can see the above piece of code being triggered from the JS script I injected (the content script), but I'm guessing I'm not "listening for it" correctly in the popup.

This is my code:

**Content script** (function runs at runtime)

```
function getLocalStorageItems() {
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({task: "retrieve-local"}, function(response) 
  {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
}
```

I've kept the example function as intact as possible.

**Popup js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => 
  {
    if ( request.task == "retrieve-local" ) {
      console.log('retrieve-local');
  }
});
```

**Manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Maxxton Dev Extension",
  "description": "Extension for Maxxton Developers",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["injected.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

I never see the console.log being registered in the popup.

I thought it might have to do with the fact I'm trying `chrome.runtime.onMessage` since sending the message from the popup is `chrome.tabs.query`. So I tried changing it to `chrome.tabs.onMessage`, but that didn't do anything also.

Now I'm thinking it's maybe not even possible because the popup is dormant/not active. But I'm not sure. And I can't find anything about this issue.

Comment: Is this popup a "page action"? If so, are you aware it has its own log page? You need to open it, inspect one of its elements and go to the console tab of the new window that appears. But shouldn't you be using a "background" script instead? A "page action" ceases to exist when it's not popped.

Comment: Can you share your manifest regarding where you register "popup.js"?

Comment: I've added my manifest. I'm aware of the separate log page. I open the popup, click > inspect element and check the console there.
I don't know what a background script is (yet) so I don't really know if I should be using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this work with a background scritp. I don't know how "browser_action" works, but when I was trying with "page_action" I noticed the page was recreated whenever I clicked the button (so, it would probably not exist and not be listening if not currently popped).

I suggest that you keep your data in the background instead, and make both the content and the popup communicate with the background.

Add to your manifest:

```
"background": {
   "scripts": [
     //"you_probably_have_something_here_to_register_browser_action?", 
     "background_data_manager.js", //this will be your script to manage data
   ],
   "persistent": false
},
```

Put your listener and all the code to handle data inside the file `background_data_manater.js`.

To access the background console, go to the Chrome tools and open the extensions page with developer mode on. You will see a little link about views in your extension there. This link opens the console for the background.

You should see the expected logs in that console.

Comment: When searching about background scripts after you mentioned it, I kind of figured out the same. That communication between my content script and popup is not possible in the direction I want and I should use the background script for all storage logic. Extra thanks for the developer tools tip for the background script :)